# Список после фильтра слепил элементы

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки, list

Задачка была такая, что подается на вход строка `(N=str(input()))` Строка содержит буквы и символы (ваще рандом) и надо, во-первых, убрать все символы и буквы (чтобы цифры остались) и после нужно убрать все повторяющийся цифры, расположить их в порядке убывания (чтобы получилось наибольшее число)
Все было бы просто,если бы не то,что через вот этот код:

```
import re
a=str(input('Введите текст : '))
print(list(filter(None, re.split(r'\D', a))))
```

Пример ввода:

```
234привет456.
```

Пример вывода:

```
['234','456']
```

Таким образом мой желаемый вывод на данном этапе это все цифры по отдельности, а итоговый вывод для ввода таков: `65432`! В питоне новичок, начал переходить с паскаля, а экзамен уже скоро...

Answer (score 3):

Не нужны тут регулярные выражения, если я правильно понял задание

```
print(*sorted({int(c) for c in input('Введите текст: ') if c.isnumeric()}, reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте:

```
import re

text = input('Введите текст: ')
items = sorted(set(map(int, re.findall(r'\d', text))), reverse=True)
print(items)
```

---

Еще вариант без регулярки через функциональный стиль:

```
text = input('Введите текст: ')
items = sorted(set(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, text))), reverse=True)
print(items)
```

- `filter` переберет каждый символ строки, оставив только цифры
- `map` цифры-строки переведет в `int`
- `set` приведет результат в множество, удалив дубликаты
- `sorted` отсортирует по убыванию

Comment: Так же склеивает числа,то есть из строки: 'аб5как56решить78' он выдаст ЧИСЛА,не цифры в порядке убывания: [78, 56, 5] . а хотелось бы какой-то такой вывод [8,7,6,5]

Comment: @ОлегСоколовский, поправил